# ng-selected value is not correctly passed to ng-model

Tags: angular-ngmodel, angular-ngselect

```
<select name="taskBoard" id="" ng-model="newTask.taskBoard">
  <option value="{{board}}" ng-repeat="board in boards track by $index" 
   ng-selected="board==showboard.board">{{board}}</option>
</select>
```

When I manually select the value from options, it can be bound with ng-model.But if ng-selected condition is true, the "selected" value will not be bound with ng-model, instead, null will be bound.

How can I change the code?

Comment: In the statement `board == showboard.board`, where are you getting `showboard` from?